# ManualResetEvent verseus Async/Await

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following class to enqueue/dequeue objects (wait on response).

```
public class PendingQueue<TValue> : Queue<TValue>, IDisposable
{
    private ManualResetEvent QueueDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public PendingQueue() : base() { }

    public new void Enqueue(TValue item)
    {
        base.Enqueue(item);

        this.QueueDone.Set();
    }

    public new TValue Dequeue()
    {
        this.QueueDone.WaitOne();

        TValue result = base.Dequeue();

        this.QueueDone.Reset();

        return result;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.QueueDone.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Basically, when I want to "halt" my script and wait for a response, I just use the following code:

```
   public bool SomeMethod()
{
    this.PendingQueue = new PendingQueue<bool>();

    return this.PendingQueue.Dequeue();
}
```

And then, I simply use PendingQueue to enqueue a boolean object and it returns that object.

Now, my problem is that it makes the **whole** thread stuck. I'm using this for scripts (compiled using the CodeDomProvider in C#). I used to use a TaskCompletionSource and then use await/async, but I want to use this class because I don't really like tasks.

How to make it *not* stuck the whole thread like async/await does? I don't want to run the scripts (when I execute them) on a different thread.

Thanks.

Comment: *I want to use this class because I don't really like tasks.* "I refuse to use idioms because I don't like them and now my code doesn't work properly"

Comment: @ta.speot.is The main reason I'm not using tasks because it makes me use the Task return type in my execution method and the async keyword as well, which is quite annoying because I have to manually add it when I automatically add the abstract class method.

Comment: ["manually"](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/files/2011/11/make_method_async.png)

Answer (score 1):

First, `PendingQueue` is pretty broken if you use it in any other way than you're currently using it. Say, if you have two items enqueued before dequeueing one.

> Now, my problem is that it makes the whole thread stuck.

That's the whole point of `ManualResetEvent` and other traditional threading synchronization primitives.

> How to make it not stuck the whole thread like async/await does?

You use `async`/`await` and `Task`s. This is the entire point of their existence.